# Storage issue - Invalid DWORD count - how to troubleshoot

Tags: raid, storage, sas

Hoping someone a bit more knowledgeable might be able to point me in the right direction please!

Having issues with a server, I believe it could be related to either RAID controller \ backplane \ cables , but looking for some advice.

Here are the details  -

Server - Dell Poweredge R410
Storage - 250GB RAID 1 Array
RAID controller - Dell SAS IR/6 (LSI Logic SAS1068)
OS - Ubuntu server 14.04 (x64)

Problem summary -

Recently the server has started to kernel panic, requiring a reboot to restore service. Occasionally seeing "rejecting I/O to offline device" logged to TTY output. I believe the underlying storage is going offline intermittently, sometimes causing the OS to kernel panic.

The RAID array is healthy and in sync -

```
ioc0 vol_id 0 type IM, 2 phy, 232 GB, state OPTIMAL, flags ENABLED
ioc0 phy 1 scsi_id 1 ATA      WDC WD2500AAJS-7 3E02, 232 GB, state ONLINE, flags NONE
ioc0 phy 0 scsi_id 8 ATA      WDC WD2500JS-75N 2E04, 232 GB, state ONLINE, flags NONE
```

When looking at SAS diagnostics, I'm seeing the INVALID DWORD counter increment occasionally.

```
Adapter Phy 0:  Link Up
  Invalid DWord Count                                       1,962
  Running Disparity Error Count                             1,772
  Loss of DWord Synch Count                                     0
  Phy Reset Problem Count                                       2

Adapter Phy 1:  Link Up
  Invalid DWord Count                                       1,402
  Running Disparity Error Count                             1,342
  Loss of DWord Synch Count                                     0
  Phy Reset Problem Count                                       0
```

I reset these stats.. after the first time I booted the server since resetting the counter, "Adapter Phy 1" displayed the following -

```
Adapter Phy 1:  Link Up
  Invalid DWord Count                                       1,402
  Running Disparity Error Count                             1,342
```

Adapter Phy 0 displayed 0 for both counts.

The server has been up for 4 days. Checking the counters this morning, I can see that Adapter Phy 1: counts are steady , but the invalid DWORD count for Adapter Phy 0 has incremented to  -

```
Adapter Phy 0:  Link Up
  Invalid DWord Count                                       1,962
  Running Disparity Error Count                             1,772
  Phy Reset Problem Count                                       2
```

Also, the PHY reset problem count has incremented to 2, but I'm not fully aware of the implications of this.

The server is showing no signs of misbehaviour at the moment, but going by recent experience it's only a matter of time before it kernel panics again.

Could the invalid DWORD count and PHY reset be indicative of a cabling \ backplane problem (as the RAID controller has already being replaced) or is there anything else I should be taking into consideration here?

Cheers